# Adding a field to a feature layer from a dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins

I'm currently working in ArcGIS with shapefiles that have a code (1-100) in the attribute table, but no name. Bear in mind that there are over 10000 polygons in this layer. In addition to this feature layer, I have a separate CSV file that has only 2 rows, the code (again, 1-100) and a corresponding name. Understandably this CSV file is much smaller than the attribute table.

How do I go about adding a field onto the shapefile attribute table that has the name that comes from the CSV file? Here's a sample of tables in case the question isn't clear.

### The Current Attribute Table

| Shapefile info | More info | SHAPEFILE CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blahblahblah | xxxxxxxx | 1 |
| blaahblah | xxxxxxxx | 2 |
| blahblahblahblah | xxxxxxxx | 3 |
| bbbbbbbbbb | xxxxxxxx | 1 |
| aaaaaaaaaa | xxxxxxxx | 1 |
| cccccccccc | xxxxxxxx | 3 |
| nnnnnnnnnn | xxxxxxxx | 2 |

### The associated CSV file

| Code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vanilla |
| 2 | Strawberry |
| 3 | Chocolate |

### The Desired Goal (keep in mind that this is attached to a shapefile)

| Shapefile info | More info | SHAPEFILE CODE | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blahblahblah | xxxxxxxx | 1 | Vanilla |
| blaahblah | xxxxxxxx | 2 | Strawberry |
| blahblahblahblah | xxxxxxxx | 3 | Chocolate |
| bbbbbbbbbb | xxxxxxxx | 1 | Vanilla |
| aaaaaaaaaa | xxxxxxxx | 1 | Vanilla |
| cccccccccc | xxxxxxxx | 3 | Chocolate |
| nnnnnnnnnn | xxxxxxxx | 2 | Strawberry |

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward.  Do some research on ArcGIS and 'joins', as well as on creating new fields and calculating field values.  If you get stuck, come back here, edit your question to explain what you did, and where you got stuck.  Hint:  Use either "Add Join" or "Join Field".